# beautifulsoup cant get all data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

this code get must data in the webpage but not whole data.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=22811176775480091'
html_data = requests.get(url).text
csecval = re.search(r"CSecVal='(\d+)", html_data).group(1)
i = re.search(r'i=(\d+)', url).group(1)

d = []
while not d:
    data = requests.get('http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfodata.aspx', params={'i': i, 'c': csecval}).text
    d = data.split(';')
print(d)
```

this code cant found data like this
eg. EPS:    481 P/E:    61.12   P/Eگروه:    45.81

Comment: It looks tike the data is getting updated by JS. Beautifulsoup4 won't be able to capture this. You might want to use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sector P/E and Estimated EPS are stored inside the HTML documet. The P/E value is computed on the fly. For example:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=22811176775480091'
html_data = requests.get(url).text
csecval = re.search(r"CSecVal='(\d+)", html_data).group(1)
i = re.search(r'i=(\d+)', url).group(1)

sector_pe = re.search(r"SectorPE='(.*?)'", html_data).group(1)
estimated_eps = re.search(r"EstimatedEPS='(.*?)'", html_data).group(1)


d = []
while not d:
    data = requests.get('http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfodata.aspx', params={'i': i, 'c': csecval}).text
    # print(data)
    d = data.split(';')

pe = float(d[0].split(',')[3]) / float(estimated_eps)
print(sector_pe, pe, estimated_eps)
```

Prints:

```
45.81 61.12266112266112 481
```